# Given all permutations of a set with n elements and the mth permutation, find m

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For example, if I have a set of all permutations of the set {1, 2, 3, 4} and the permutation 1, 4, 3, 2 how do i calculate which element of the set it is without calculating all the permutations?

Comment: Well, how are you listing the permutations?  If lexicographic, then count those that begin with $1$, and so on.

Comment: See also the reverse, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717475/finding-position-of-specific-permutation-in-alphabetically-ordered-list-of-permu?noredirect=1&lq=1